# Нековзкий, протиковзкий/неслизький, протислизький

Tags: вибір-слова, синоніми

Треба надати опис колодці кухонного ножа з рифленою поверхнею, що запобігає висковзуванню/вислизанню з долоні. Як її назвати? За тлумаченням СУМ-11,

> СЛИЗЬКИ́Й, а, е.
>
> 1. Дуже гладкий, який майже не утворює тертя, на якому важко втриматися, встояти; який ледве утримує на собі кого-, що-небудь;
>      ковзкий. Христя спускається з гори. Та й слизька ж яка! Ноги так і
>      йдуть; коли б ще не впасти (Панас Мирний, III, 1954, 242); Він давно
>      згубив свого картузика, кілька разів падав на слизькій дорозі (Михайло
>      Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 135); Брязнули десь засуви, і в каземат важко
>      впав чоловік, зірвавшись в слизької драбинки (Зінаїда Тулуб, Людолови,
>      II, 1957, 103); Земля після дощу стала слизькою (Михайло Томчаній,
>      Готель.., 1960, 12);
>
>    //  Якого ледве можна втримати в руках; порский.
>      Таке слизьке, що й двома руками не вдержиш (Українські народні
>      прислів'я та приказки, 1955, 295); Назустріч мені поспішали в базару
>      жінки.., з їх кошиків, повних слизького м'яса, виглядали барвінок і
>      первоцвіт (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 361); Важкі колоди й
>      слизькі дошки випорскували з рук, падали в ковбані разом з людьми
>      (Олександр Довженко, Зачарована Десна, 1957, 305);
>
> КОВЗКИ́Й, а, е.
>
> 1. Такий, що не утворює тертя й на якому ледве тримається хто-, що-небудь. Подовгу стояла Горпина на ковзкому краю безодні (Зінаїда
>      Тулуб, Людолови, I, 1957, 332); Набравши в льоху решето яблук та слив,
>      швець без пригод вибрався по ковзких східцях нагору (Володимир Бабляк,
>      Вишневий сад, 1960, 229);
>
>    //  Такий, якого важко втримати в руках;
>      дуже гладкий, слизький. Ковзкий, відполірований мозолястими руками
>      дубовий рогач вертівся в руках Уляни (Віталій Логвиненко, Літа..,
>      1960, 57).

Яке слово більш доречне і яку форму на позначення відсутності ознаки/запобігання дії (протиковзкий/-слизький, нековзкий/-слизький чи антиковзкий/-слизький?) слід вжити?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Проти" передбачає активну дію / запобігання і "протиковзкий" - це той, що перешкоджає ковзанню.  Скажімо, якби з ножа висипався тальк на долоню, або там були якісь упори (як гарда в рапіри), то можна було би говорити про "протиковзкий". Поверхня активно не перешкоджає. Нековзкість є її властивістю, тому "нековзкий" коректніше. Водночас зрозуміло, що для *маркетингу* краще написати "протиковзкий" щоб підкреслити, що ті, хто створював ніж, цілеспрямовано намагалися запобігти ковзкості. Тобто тут вибір швидше не лінгвістичний, а практичний (для чого пишемо).
"Антиковзкий" - це взагалі недоречно, на мою думку, оскільки є аналогом "протиковзкого", але із запозиченою часткою.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE!
Ця відповідь дуже виграла б, якби ґрунтувалася не лише на логіці і здоровому глузді, але також на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо.
Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінку [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).